# What does the equation of a refracted ray trace mean?

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics

I am doing a ray trace to a refracted vector. I read in some PDF files that:
vector($\mathbf{t}$) is the refracted ray, vector($\mathbf{i}$) is the incident ray, the angle $\theta_t$ is the refraction angle and angle $\theta_i$ is the incident angle. To calculate the refracted ray we use this equation:

$$\mathbf{t}=\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\mathbf{i}+\left(\frac{\eta_1}{\eta_2}\cos \theta_i-\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta_t} \right)$$

But I really didn't get what this equation represents. What information does it give about vector $\mathbf{t}$?

Comment: Right off the bat I can see that something is wrong here, the first part of your equation is a vector (scalar multiplied by $\hat{\imath}$), but it is added to a scalar.  Maybe the second part is supposed to be multiplied by the surface normal, $\hat{n}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it looks to me like there's a mistake in the equation, I'll try to re-derive it.  Hopefully that will make it a little clearer what's going on.

We'll start with [Snell's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law):
$$
\frac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}=\frac{n_2}{n_1}
$$
Now there are several vectors we're going to deal with, I'll go through them one by one.

- $\hat\imath$: The vector in the direction of the **i**ncoming ray.
- $\hat{t}$: The vector in the direction of the **t**ransmitted ray.
- $\hat{n}$: The vector perpendicular to the surface, the **n**ormal vector.
- $\hat{n}_\perp$: A vector perpendicular to the normal vector, in the plane of $\hat\imath$ and $\hat{t}$.

Let's write out some relations between these vectors.  We can express $\hat\imath$ and $\hat{t}$ in terms of the direction of the surface and their angles to the surface.

$$
\hat\imath = -\cos\theta_1\hat{n}+\sin\theta_1\hat{n}_\perp \\
\hat{t} = -\cos\theta_2\hat{n}+\sin\theta_2\hat{n}_\perp
$$
(the minus sign comes from the fact that the ray is headed *towards* the surface.)

Since we don't know $\hat{n}_\perp$, let's eliminate it from those equations.
$$
\hat{n}_\perp = \csc\theta_1\hat\imath+\cot\theta_1\hat{n} \\
\hat{n}_\perp = \csc\theta_2\hat{t}+\cot\theta_2\hat{n} \\
\csc\theta_1\hat\imath+\cot\theta_1\hat{n} = \csc\theta_2\hat{t}+\cot\theta_2\hat{n}
$$
Let's try to solve for $\hat{t}$.
$$
\csc\theta_2\hat{t}=\csc\theta_1\hat\imath+\cot\theta_1\hat{n}-\cot\theta_2\hat{n} \\
\hat{t}=\frac{\sin\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1}\hat\imath+\cos\theta_1\frac{\sin\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1}\hat{n}-\cos\theta_2\hat{n}
$$
Those ratios of $\sin$'s are in Snell's law, so let's replace them and consolidate terms.
$$
\hat{t}=\frac{n_1}{n_2}\hat\imath+\left(\cos\theta_1\frac{n_1}{n_2}-\cos\theta_2\right)\hat{n}
$$
Finally let's replace the $\cos$ with a $\sin$.
$$
\hat{t}=\frac{n_1}{n_2}\hat\imath+\left(\cos\theta_1\frac{n_1}{n_2}-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta_2}\right)\hat{n}
$$
So we've recovered (almost) your original expression.  It gives you the direction of the transmitted ray given the direction of the surface normal and incoming ray.

Note that $\cos\theta_1=\hat\imath\cdot\hat{n}$ and $\sin\theta_2=\frac{n_1}{n_2}\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta_1}$.

In order to implement this equation, you'll need to add and multiply vectors, so let's talk [vector arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector).  For a more complete understanding I recommend you do some reading up on the subject.

A vector $\vec{v}$ has 3 components (in 3d space), I'll denote them $v_x$, $v_y$, and $v_z$.

The product of a vector $\vec{v}$ and a scalar (regular number) $a$ is a vector:
$$
a\times(v_x,v_y,v_z) = (av_x,av_y,av_z)
$$

The sum of two vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$ is a vector:
$$
(v_x,v_y,v_z)+(u_x,u_y,u_z) = (v_x+u_x,v_y+u_y,v_z+u_z)
$$

The dot product of two vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$ is a scalar:
$$
(v_x,v_y,v_z)\cdot(u_x,u_y,u_z) = v_x u_x+v_y u_y+v_z u_z
$$

The magnitude (length) of a vector $\vec{v}$ is $|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}$.  Directions, like the directions of the light rays in raytracing, are represented by unit vectors: vectors with unit magnitude.  We typically denote unit vectors with a hat instead of an arrow (e.g. $\hat{n}$).  For a unit vector $\hat{n}$, it's always true that $\hat{n}\cdot\hat{n}=1$.  To make a unit vector (normalize) any vector, simply divide that vector by its magnitude (equivalent to multiplying by one over the magnitude).

Note that you'll sometimes see the three coordinate axes labeled by $i$, $j$, and $k$ or $1$, $2$, and $3$.  Also, you'll see vectors written as sums of the unit vectors along the coordinate axes, e.g:
$$
\vec{v}=(v_x,v_y,v_z) \\
=v_x\hat{x}+v_y\hat{y}+v_z\hat{z} \\
=v_x\hat{i}+v_y\hat{j}+v_z\hat{k} \\
=v_x\hat{e}_1+v_y\hat{e}_2+v_z\hat{e}_3
$$

Comment: thank you for your post. but actually I didn't get the main point I need, if I need to deal with the refracted vector (I have it as 3D) as its (x,y,z) components.Can I know them from the last equation you wrote?@2012rcampion

Comment: @user3159060 I'll modify my post to include a little primer on vector arithmetic.

Comment: @user3159060 If this answered your question, please mark this as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.